# How to implement First Order free shipping

Tags: magento2.3.1

Magento 2.3.1: How to implement First Order free shipping

Comment: Create cart price rule with free shipping, use `Uses per Customer` option 1.

Comment: i want only free shipping option applicable in first order.after first order consider the shipping charge.is it posible

Comment: Yes possible....It applicable for logged in customers only or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Admin panel->Marketing->Cart price Rules` create a new rule.

Create a rule with below configuration to apply free shipping for logged in customer for next first order.

Fill all the required fields like `Rule name, Websites etc`

Customer Group -> **Select other than Not Logged IN value**

Uses per Customer -> **Should be 1 (To apply once per customer)**

Action(tab) -> Free Shipping -> **For matching items only**

Don't create any action rule, then only it will apply all the customer with any products.

Save and flush the cache to see the results.

**Note:** It will work only for logged in customer

Comment: How to display discount shipping charge at that particular order

Comment: Can you please explain briefly what is your exact requirement?

Comment: Seems your question is different please ask a separate question...May be someone knows..I'll let you know once got solution asap.

Comment: Ok your first solution is done.Then want to display discount in shopping cart.Discount means deducted shipping charge

Answer (score 0):

Coupon.

Something like code freeship.

Single use per customer.

Can do it with magento core - no modification. Plus can track campaign with usage statistics. For example have certain codes advertised on certain platforms. For example freeshipfb (Facebook) and so on.